# How to destructure an enum's fields and as a whole value at the same time?

Tags: enums, rust

I want to match an enum variant, process it and then pass it further. The code should look like this:

```
enum Event {
    WindowEvent {
        event: WindowEvent,
        window_id: usize,
    },
}
enum WindowEvent {
    Resized(u8),
}

struct Demo {
    size: u8,
}

impl Demo {
    fn reproduction(&mut self, event: Event) {
        match event {
            e
            @
            Event::WindowEvent {
                event: WindowEvent::Resized(size),
                ..
            } => {
                self.size = size;
                self.handle_event(e);
            }
        }
    }

    fn handle_event(&self, _event: Event) {}
}
```

This code doesn't pass the borrow checker:

```
error[E0007]: cannot bind by-move with sub-bindings
  --> src/lib.rs:18:13
   |
18 | /             e
19 | |             @
20 | |             Event::WindowEvent {
21 | |                 event: WindowEvent::Resized(size),
22 | |                 ..
23 | |             } => {
   | |_____________^ binds an already bound by-move value by moving it

error[E0658]: pattern bindings after an `@` are unstable
  --> src/lib.rs:21:45
   |
21 |                 event: WindowEvent::Resized(size),
   |                                             ^^^^
   |
   = note: see issue #65490 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/65490> for more information

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `event`
  --> src/lib.rs:21:45
   |
16 |       fn reproduction(&mut self, event: Event) {
   |                                  ----- move occurs because `event` has type `Event`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
17 |           match event {
18 | /             e
19 | |             @
20 | |             Event::WindowEvent {
21 | |                 event: WindowEvent::Resized(size),
   | |                                             ^^^^ value used here after move
22 | |                 ..
23 | |             } => {
   | |_____________- value moved here
```

I can fully destructure `event` and construct it again on pass to `handle_event`, but this seems wrong. Why should I construct a new object when I can pass the existing one? Why should I care about other fields (there can be plenty of them!) when I could use the wildcard `..`:

```
match event {
    Event::WindowEvent {
        event: WindowEvent::Resized(size),
        window_id,
    } => {
        self.size = size;
        self.handle_event(Event::WindowEvent {
            event: WindowEvent::Resized(size),
            window_id,
        });
    }
}
```

I found another solution that requires matching twice:

```
match event {
    e
    @
    Event::WindowEvent {
        event: WindowEvent::Resized(_),
        ..
    } => {
        if let Event::WindowEvent {
            event: WindowEvent::Resized(size),
            ..
        } = e
        {
            self.size = size;
        }
        self.handle_event(e);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to destucture an enum variant without losing the original value?

Comment: It seems to me your problem could be solved simply by writing `self.handle_event(event)` and not trying to bind `e` at all. Does that fix the problem? If not, we'll need more detail.

Comment: After *attempting* to fill in the gaps of your code, [it works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=53fa2cf6b08110417b0ce1916c011936), so it's highly unclear what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you! The "#![feature(bindings_after_at)]" is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, reuse the `event` value without trying to do fancy pattern matching techniques:

```
match event {
    Event::WindowEvent {
        event: WindowEvent::Resized(size),
        ..
    } => {
        self.size = size;
        self.handle_event(event);
    }
}
```

---

In the future, there will be another option. As the compiler's error messages state:

> error[E0007]: cannot bind by-move with sub-bindings
>
> error[E0658]: pattern bindings after an `@` are unstable
>
> note: see [issue #65490](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/65490) for more information

On nightly Rust, you can add `#![feature(bindings_after_at)]` and then change your code to match on a reference:

```
fn reproduction(&mut self, event: Event) {
    match &event {
        e
        @
        Event::WindowEvent {
            event: WindowEvent::Resized(size),
            ..
        } => {
            self.size = *size;
            self.handle_event(e);
        }
    }
}

fn handle_event(&self, _event: &Event) {}
```

If the enums you are matching on are `Copy`, you won't need to take the reference.